# Stuck on this probability question

Tags: probability, self-study

Team A leads by 3 games vs. team B and 4 games vs. team C. Of the 9 remaining games, Teams A and C will play each other 6 more times and other teams 3 more times. Team B will play all 9 remaining games against other teams. With each game's result being a 50/50 coin flip, what is the probability of a 3-way tie?

I have the results of all instances where there is a 3-way tie and will post it soon (have to run), but am mainly having trouble thinking about the probability (I'm assuming its all of these instances of a 3-way tie divided by all the ways in which these games can be played).

---

[image]

I'm seeing the following as the combination of wins that lead to a 3-way tie. Having said that, I'm unsure as to how to get the total probability.

Comment: Please add self-study tag.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to answer this question without also knowing by how many games B leads C.

Comment: Team B leads C by a game (same division).

Comment: could we bump our questions so that they appear back on top?